# php session variables problem in Firefox

Tags: php, firefox, session-variables

I set several php session variables in an initial php file. In all other ajax loaded php files the value of those session variables is updated only after refreshing the page. This happens only in Firefox. Does anyone know what may cause this to happen? In IE everything works fine.

Comment: Is there `session_start()` at the top of all your scripts, AJAX or conventional?

Comment: Probably the ajax requests are fired after the file has loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution. There was a cache issue. Write:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

after

```
session_start();
```

in all your conventional scripts.

Comment: or just use post ajax request when you write variables, and get when you read them

Comment: oh man, you are the hero of the day. here was my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961920/joomla-2-5-jfactorygetsession-seems-to-be-caching-in-firefox and finally after adding the headers before reseting the session variable caused firefox to reset the session variable finally!. Thanx