# Joomla 2.5 JFactory::getSession(); seems to be caching in firefox

Tags: php, ajax, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a php file in includes directory. It's usability is to display a captcha Image.
In that file I set a session variable like this:

```
$code = codegenerator();
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('security_code', $code);
```

This Session variable is set from an image `src` that calls that method from a controller.

Then I call a controller to check that session that was set
(this method is trigerd with ajax from an iframe) and in that method I do this

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$seccode=$session->get('security_code');
echo $seccode.':'.rand();
```

The result is as expected the first time, the code that was set and a random number.
If I refresh that page the captcha image gets reset with a new code and gets displayed. 
But when I triger the check event again, I get the previous code with a new random number.
That `rand()` there is a proof that `JFactory::getSession();` is cached because I get the new random number but the same previous code and not the new as supposed to. So it's not that ajax that is caching something here.

How can I avoid `JFactory::getSession();` geting cached from firefox? 
This happens only in firefox. Internet explorer and chrome seem to display the session code correctly. If I clear firefox cash and refresh the page it still doesn't work. It's like it's cached for ever. If I close firefox and open it again, then everything seems to work as the first time, but then I have the same issue again.

Here is the code that generates the captcha

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
class CaptchaSecurityImages {

    var $font='monofont.ttf';


    function generateCode($characters) {
        /* list all possible characters, similar looking characters and vowels have been removed */
        $possible = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
        $code = '';
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $characters) { 
            $code .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
            $i++;
        }
        return $code;
    }

    function CaptchaSecurityImages($width='220',$height='40',$characters='6') {
        $code = $this->generateCode($characters);

        //$font='includes'.DS.'monofont.ttf';
        $font='monofont.ttf';
        $this->font=$font;

        $session =& JFactory::getSession();
        $session->set('security_code', $code);


        /* font size will be 75% of the image height */
        $font_size = $height * 0.75;
        $image = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Cannot initialize new GD image stream');

        /* set the colours */
        $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
        $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 20, 40, 100);
        $noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 100, 120, 180);
        /* generate random dots in background */
        for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/3; $i++ ) {
            imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 1, 1, $noise_color);
        }
        /* generate random lines in background */
        for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/150; $i++ ) {
            imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $noise_color);
        }
        /* create textbox and add text */


        $textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $this->font, $code) or die('Error in imagettfbbox function');
        $x = ($width - $textbox[4])/2;
        $y = ($height - $textbox[5])/2;
        imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $this->font , $code) or die('Error in imagettftext function');
        /* output captcha image to browser */

        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($image);
        imagedestroy($image);

    }

}
?>
```

And here is the code that is called by the ajax

```
public function checkCaptchaSecurityCode(){
        $securitycode = JRequest::getVar('securitycode');           
        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        $seccode=$session->get('security_code');        

        echo $seccode.':'.rand();

        die();
    }
```

and here is the ajax call

```
<?php $checkCaptchaSecurityCode = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=participate&task=checkCaptchaSecurityCode&tmpl=component&format=raw'); ?>
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
            jQuery.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "<?php echo $checkCaptchaSecurityCode ?>",
                  cache: false,
                  data: { securitycode: jQuery("#security_code").val() }
                }).done(function( msg ) {
                  alert( msg );
            });
```

please help

Comment: This is a very weird bug, since the browser shouldn't actually have any of this data. All session data is stored on the server, with just the session id being sent to the client. The best I can think would be to try a `$session=clear('security_code')` before re-declaring it to see if that impacts the value.

Comment: did anyone found a fix ?

Comment: what I actually did is add a parameter id each time I make the call. This is how I managed to fix my problem. This is an example :
$checkCaptchaSecurityCode = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=participate&task=checkCaptchaSecurityCode&tmpl=component&format=raw&ver=1');
and each time I make the call, I change the ver to 2, and then back to 1 again. This is how I tricked the session, But this does not address the issue, it's only a work oround

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but calling the clear method before setting a new session variable fixed the problem.

```
    $session = & JFactory::getSession();
    /* this way unset data from the session store */
    $session->clear('security_code');
    /* and now set the new value */
    $session->set('security_code', $code);
```

It works even if is the first time you are declaring a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you **posting/getting** to **mydomain.com** when from www.mydomain.com ? 
This would cause joomla to create a new session I believe.

Comment: no, the issue is not about changing the session, its keeping the session without changing it.